# How Can I parse a PPM file and store RGB values in three separate 2D arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, rgb, ppm

My code tries to loop through the PPM file and is supposed to ignore the header information. Once it is done, it is supposed to add red, green, and blue numbers to 2D int arrays. The x and y values for the color channel arrays are supposed to be the same for the associated color channel array of the pixel.

The header of the file is this:

```
P3
200 200
255
```

There is an empty line below the 255 in the header. The individual pixel data begins after the header on a new line below the aforementioned line.

Here is the Java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
     

public class ImageScaling3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        String tempString = "";
        int tempNum = 0;
        int countX = 0;
        int countY = 0;
        int newLineCount = 0;
        int ArrayBoxNum = 0;
        boolean canParsePixels = false;
        
        int redMap[][] = new int[200][200];
        int greenMap[][] = new int[200][200];
        int blueMap[][] = new int[200][200];
        
        Path fileName = Path.of("C:/Users/Mark/eclipse-workspace/ImageScaling/Lenna100 Working.ppm");
         
        String data = Files.readString(fileName);
        
        for (int cursor = 0; cursor < data.length(); cursor++) {
            
            if (data.charAt(cursor) == '\n') {
              newLineCount++;
                if (newLineCount == 4) {
                    canParsePixels = true;
                }// Ending bracket of inner if
            }// Ending bracket of outer if
            
            if (canParsePixels == true) {
                switch(ArrayBoxNum) {
                  case 0:
                      if (data.charAt(cursor) != ' ') {
                      tempString += data.charAt(cursor);
                      }// Ending bracket of if
                      else {
                          tempString = tempString.trim();
                          tempNum = Integer.parseInt(tempString);
                          redMap[countX][countY] = tempNum;
                          tempString = "";
                          ArrayBoxNum = 1;
                      }// Ending bracket of else
                  break;
                    
                  case 1:
                      if (data.charAt(cursor) != ' ') {
                          tempString += data.charAt(cursor);
                          }// Ending bracket of if
                          else {
                              tempString = tempString.trim();
                              tempNum = Integer.parseInt(tempString);
                              greenMap[countX][countY] = tempNum;
                              tempString = "";
                              ArrayBoxNum = 2;
                          }// Ending bracket of else
                    
                  break;
                  
                  case 2:
                      if (data.charAt(cursor) != ' ') {
                          tempString += data.charAt(cursor);
                          }// Ending bracket of if
                          else {
                              tempString = tempString.trim();
                              tempNum = Integer.parseInt(tempString);
                              blueMap[countX][countY] = tempNum;
                              tempString = "";
                              ArrayBoxNum = 3;
                          }// Ending bracket of else
                    
                  break;
                    
                  case 3:
                      
                      if (countX < 200) {
                        countX++;
                        }// Ending bracket of if
                        else {
                            countX = 0;
                            countY++;
                            if (countY == 200) {
                                break;
                            }// Ending bracket of if
                        }// Ending bracket of else
                 break;
                    
                }// Ending bracket of switch
         
                
            }// Ending bracket of if
            
        }// Ending bracket of for loop
       
     for (int y = 0; y < 200; y++) {
         for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
             System.out.print(redMap[x][y] + greenMap[x][y] + blueMap[x][y]);
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
       
              
               
              
              
        
        
        
    }// Ending bracket of method main
    
}// Ending bracket of class ImageScaling3
```

At the end, when I print out the values, I only get 0's except for 3 different single digit numbers.

Comment: this source code may be helpful for you to [review](http://darnok.org/programming/face-recognition/PPMFile.java)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to study that and see if I can correct what went wrong.